# jQuery find elements that do not have specified ancestor

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, selector

I have to find some elements that do not have specified ancestor.
Example Code:

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="pic1.jpg" />
</a>
<p>
  <img src="pic2.jpg" />
</p>
```

I want to select all `img` tags not wrapped in `a` tag.

How can I do it?

Comment: is the image is wraped in p tags?

Answer (score 4):

I did it with this code:

```js
$("img").filter(function(){
  return $(this).closest('a').length === 0
}).css("border", "3px solid red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">
  <img src="pic1.jpg" />
</a>
<p>
  <img src="pic2.jpg" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this work using simpler solution.

Use `:not()` instead of `.filter( function )`.

```js
$("img:not(a img)").css("border", "3px solid red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">
  <img src="pic1.jpg" />
</a>
<p>
  <img src="pic2.jpg" />
</p>
```

Comment: that's great! I'll use it.

Answer (score 0):

Can do using parent also:

```
var images =  $('img').filter(function(){
  if(!$(this).parent().is('a')) {
    return $(this);  
  }
});
```